# Extract/Query/Read SQLite database row by ID

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a list, and i want to extract all data at specific id,
This is what i tried, but i cant get it to work:

```
public Cursor fetchById(long id) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID, KEY_MATCH, KEY_TIME, KEY_BOOKMAKERS, KEY_ODDS1 },
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }
```

By debugging, i can see the data in "cursor" being:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41e7a1c8

This i hoped would be a complete string of the other data at that id

This is my database:

[image]

And here is some more database info:
[image]

Here is the activity to call the method:

Choice.java

```
public class Choice extends Activity {

    private BetsDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    Long value;
    TextView idshow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choicelayout);

        //Database
        dbHelper = new BetsDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null){
             value = extras.getLong("id");
        }

    String id = String.valueOf(value);

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchById(value);  //Here i call the function     

        idshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        idshow.setText(cursor);

    }
```

And here is my databasehandler:

BetsDbAdapter.java

```
public class BetsDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_MATCH = "match";
    public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_BOOKMAKERS = "bookmakers";
    public static final String KEY_ODDS1 = "odds1";

    private static final String TAG = "BetsDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Bets.db";
    private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "BetTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "
            + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_MATCH + ","
            + KEY_TIME + "," + KEY_BOOKMAKERS + "," + KEY_ODDS1 + ","
            + " UNIQUE (" + KEY_MATCH + "));";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public BetsDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public BetsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
public long createBets(String match, String time, String bookmakers,
            String odds1) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_MATCH, match);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BOOKMAKERS, bookmakers);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ODDS1, odds1);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

public Cursor fetchById(long id) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_MATCH, KEY_TIME, KEY_BOOKMAKERS, KEY_ODDS1 },
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use cursor as the param for setText. Try

```
String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BetsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCH)) 
             + "\n" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BetsDbAdapter.KEY_TIME))
             + "\n" + ....
idshow.setText(text);
```

Comment: I think my problem lies in: BetsDbAdapter.java, in this method:
"public Cursor fetchById(long id) throws SQLException"
Since when i debug i cantt see the wanted data in cursor

Comment: How do try to see the data? From android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41e7a1c8 you get a cursor at address 41e7a1c8.

Comment: Ah ok, i accidently outcommented:

"idshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);"
So now your code works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your selection argument, you may need to surround the target value with single quotes like so:

```
KEY_ROWID + "='" + id + "'"
```

Alternatively, you could use the selectionArgs parameter as well like so:

```
String selection = KEY_ROWID + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = {id};
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_MATCH, KEY_TIME, KEY_BOOKMAKERS, KEY_ODDS1 },
                selection, seelctionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This dosnt work.. In my database KEY_ROWID is a long, in Choice.java "value" is also a long, i guess i should compare it with this? but then i cant use your answer